# Is MongooseJS Populate an Anti Pattern?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I’ve found multiple posts and guides praising the ability to do joins in Mongoose and MongoDB using the `populate()` method.

This makes me confused. If you want to do joins, shouldn’t you use an SQL database? Shouldn’t joins in MongoDB be a last resort?

Each object that is using `populate()` is required to do a second query to fetch that data. So if you fetch 100 items in a query, you need to do another 100 queries to fetch that data.  It sounds like storing it as nested schemes is a way better idea where possible.

An I wrong? Is `populate()` actually a great method that make sense? Or am I right that it’s a last resort option that you can use in cases that should be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

populate() doesn't send a `find` request for every child document per parent document.

it sends a single `find` with all child ObjectIds (of all parents!) in the filter.

example (`mongoose.set('debug', true)` console output):

```
Mongoose: parent.find({}, { fields: {} })   // was called with populate()
Mongoose: child.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId(A), ObjectId(B), ...] }})
```

and then probably "joins" parents to children in node.

so essentially, only 1 RTT was added. to avoid this as much as possible, I've denormalized some of my schemas for common use cases.

Comment: See graph in end of this article https://medium.com/dbkoda/coding-efficient-mongodb-joins-97fe0627751a it’s getting exponentially slower the more objects that need to get joined.

Comment: this article is not talking about populate()... (but about $lookup).

Comment: according to console output, and according to this issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3683 (check the oct 2017 comments)  populate does not use $lookup under the hood.

Comment: I see. So back to the original question. Is populate really a great solution as people claim? Should it be used like joins in SQL or should the developer try to design their scheme in a way so that populate is used sparingly?

Comment: iv'e read that before populate() was added to the library, people did all this "join" stuff manually.. so this new feature was a godsend for many of them. as far as choosing a DB goes, there are a lot of tradeoffs and things to consider.

Comment: imo, you should look into denormalizing your schemas to only require populates in edge / less common cases